# nodejs elastic Client Error : Mapping cannot have more than one type [default, _doc] after hosting the application to server

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Getting the following error whhile creating a new row in index

[image]

While my function is written in this format

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple mapping types are not supported in indices created in Elasticsearch 6+.

You do not need to specify the `type` parameter in your document indexing request, [it has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_index), your document will be implicitly mapped to the type set when your index itself was created.

If you still want to use multiple types, you can look into [alternatives suggested by Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html#_alternatives_to_mapping_types).

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Types will be deprecated in APIs in Elasticsearch 7.0.0, and completely removed in 8.0.0.

- [Rejecting mapping update to [] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rejecting-mapping-update-to-as-the-final-mapping-would-have-more-than-1-type/124316)
- [Breaking changes in 6.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking-changes-6.0.html)
- [Removal of mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html)

Comment: Thanks for the input
I was able to solve the issue by upgrading the elastic search Server from 6.5 to 7.6